# How to replace variable in where clause in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle

I have a oracle query which will fetch data from database   and show them in gridview dynamically.The query used is `select *from Employee where Location=?Location and Age=?Age and Marks=?Marks` .Variable beginning with ? are placeholders which will be filled at runtime.Suppose here i extracted place holders by selecting drop down and got it like `Location='Chemmad' and  Marks='100'`.I need a logic to insert values i created in to the place holders and if some thing miss for example here `Age` missing, i have to capture the missing one.In nutshell i have a query for dropdown like

```
string query = "select *from Employee where Location=?Location and Age=?Age and Marks=?Marks";
```

i got the values at runtime for the place holders like

```
string values = "Location='Chemmad' and  Marks='100'";
```

so i want to replace the values with placeholders and same time need to find the missing one so here  `Age`

```
**EDIT**
```

I stored all the combinations of queries in oracle database itself :) and fetching at run time and replacing values.I think i have to find the location of = sign and need to find the words from either side??

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you want to do simple string manipulation, ie. dynamically building your where clause? Do you need help understanding how to create a parameterized sql statement for Oracle? Do you not know how to link your UI and your db/service layer? Why dont you add some expected input and expected output or something else to clarify what you are looking for in an answer.

Comment: @Igor  i edited my question, i need a simple string manupulation

Comment: Then you would have to use a expression to find the start of the where clause and replace everything after it with the column name/placeholder name pairs using AND as a separator. Or you store just up until the where clause and generate it in your code using column name/placeholder name.

Comment: I think i have to find the location of = sign and need to find the words from either side??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string strValues = "Location='Chemmad' and  Marks='100'"; // this is bad and will cause sql injection attacks.
// what you actually want is an object(s) that you can use in the parameterized query. depending on your input you then dynamically create the where part of your string. something like this:
var parameterValues = new
{
    Location = "Chemmad",
    Marks = 100
};


const string searchTerm = " where ";
var query = @"select * from Employee where Location=?Location and Age=?Age and Marks=?Marks";
var part1 = query.Substring(0, query.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
// the following line is not necessary and won't be used. It just illustrates how to get the remainder of the query.
var part2 = query.Substring(query.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) + searchTerm.Length, query.Length - part1.Length - searchTerm.Length);

var myDynamicQuery = part1 + searchTerm;
myDynamicQuery = myDynamicQuery + "Location = :location ";
myDynamicQuery = myDynamicQuery + "AND Marks = :marks ";
```

`myDynamicQuery` now contains string: `select * from Employee where Location = :location AND Marks = :marks`

Next

1. create your oracle connection
2. create your DbParameters
3. Execute your query against an oracle command object

See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) for how to properly create an Oracle connection from .NET and use a parameterized query.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SqlCommand.Parameters` to pass parameters to your query like show below. Using `string.Format` instead leaves your code vulnerable to SQL injection.

```
string commandText = "select *from Employee where Location=@Location and Age=@Age and Marks=@Marks;"

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.Char);
    command.Parameters["@Location"].Value = Location;

    command.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@Age"].Value = Age;

    command.Parameters.Add("@Marks", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@Marks"].Value = Marks;



    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
  }
```

Comment: i have edited my question.I stored all the combinations of queries in oracle database itself :) and fetching runtime and replacing values

Comment: I need a simple string manupulation in order to construct where clasue.Rest all i have done

Comment: Why are you not using a parametrised stored procedure?

Comment: can you write the simple string replacement

Comment: Simple string replacemt will leave you vulnerable to SQL injection. Especially as you are storing Employee data this can leave your company (or yourself) at risk of large fines when this data gets leaked online.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a parameterized Query with Oracle using ODP.net.  Like Jaco's response, this is much better than string replacement for numerous reasons:

1. Prevents SQL Injection
2. Manages datatypes (don't need to do any conversions on C# DateTime => Oracle's Date)
3. Eliminates the difficulty of quoting within the SQL (apostrophes, quotes, carriage returns, etc)

Example:

```
string query = "select * from Employee where " +
    "Location= :LOC and Age = :AGE and Marks = :MARKS";

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query);
cmd.Parameters.Add("LOC", "Chemmad");
cmd.Parameters.Add("AGE", 125);
cmd.Parameters.Add("MARKS", "100");

OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    object firstField = reader.GetValue(0);
}

reader.Close();
```

The `Add` where the datatype is preferable, especially when you have multiple values to assign (like in an insert or update), but if you only have a single set of parameters, then the `Add` also enables the parameter to be declared and assigned in a single statement.  In some implementations this is `AddWithValue`, but I think in Oracle it's just an overload of `Add`.

Also, note that unlike SQL Server, with Oracle you use a `:` instead of a `@` within the SQL, and you leave that character off when declaring the actual `OracleParameters`.